# Xamarin.forms plugin.FingerPrint can't be added to my Project

Tags: xamarin

I've to implement in my project fingerprint/faceid functions, and I wa trying to add the plugin.Fingerprint, but I've had this message when I added to my PCL project:

```
Could not install package 'Cross.Plugins.Fingerprint 2.1.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I tried all the stable versions of the plugin, I tried to look around for compatibility specs but with no success.
Can anyone help me?

PS: I can't use Xamarin.Essentials I tried to use it, but I've a strange issue with a webview on android project: can't navigate anymore on hyperlink.

thanks in advance to the one who answer me.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins.Fingerprint 2.1.3 is not supported for .NETPortable. check [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Fingerprint).

change to .NET Standart if possible, if not then try to find another plugin